# Не находит порт сервера

Tags: c#, http, клиент-сервер, семафоры

Сервер использует при запуске случайный порт:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureBuilder(IWebHostBuilder builder, string ip = "*") =>
        builder.UseSerilog()
               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .UseKestrel(x =>
               {
                   x.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
               })
               .UseUrls($"http://{ip}:0");
```

С клиента с помощью следующего кода хочу получить его путём пинга возможных портов:

```
private static int GetCurrentPort(IPAddress ip, IEnumerable<int> ports)
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    using var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(500);

    var availablePort = -1;

    ports.ToAsyncEnumerable().ForEachAsync(async port =>
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            var response = await $"http://{ip}:{port}".AppendPathSegment("ping").GetAsync(cts.Token);
            if (response.StatusCode is 200)
            {
                availablePort = port;
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally { semaphore.Release(); }
    }, cts.Token).Wait();

    if (availablePort == -1)
        throw new ApplicationException("Not found available server port");

    return availablePort;
}
```

Сервер при этом отвечает на запрос, но клиент всё равно выкидывает исключение `ApplicationException`. Будто не ожидает `Wait()`

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://192.168.0.0:49983/ping - -
[2023-04-27 11:38:54.452 INF] Request:
Protocol: HTTP/1.1
Method: GET
Scheme: http
PathBase:
Path: /ping
Host: 192.168.0.0:49983
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[2023-04-27 11:38:54.479 INF] Response:
StatusCode: 200
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 08:38:54 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2023-04-27 11:38:54.481 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://192.168.0.0:49983/ping - - - 200 - - 44.8413ms
```

С помощью следующего кода получаю возможные порты:

```
public static IReadOnlyList<int> GetAvaliablePorts(ushort lowerPort = MIN_PORT, ushort upperport = MAX_PORT)
{
    var ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    return Enumerable.Empty<int>()
                     .Concat(ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections().Select(x => x.LocalEndPoint.Port))
                     .Concat(ipProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners().Select(x => x.Port))
                     .Concat(ipProperties.GetActiveUdpListeners().Select(x => x.Port))
                     .Where(x => x >= lowerPort && x <= upperport)
                     .Sort().Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Использую библиотеки `Flurl` для отправки сообщений и `System.Linq.Async` для `ToAsyncEnumerable`

UPD:

Нашел реализацию и под свою проблему преобразовал её. Посмотрите, пожалуйста

```
private static async Task<int> GetCurrentPort(IPAddress ip, IEnumerable<int> ports)
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    using var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(500);

    var availablePort = -1;

    try
    {
        _ = ports.OrderDescending().WithCancellation(cts.Token).Select(async port =>
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();

            try
            {
                var response = await $"http://{ip}:{port}".AppendPathSegment("ping").GetAsync(cts.Token);
                if (response.StatusCode is 200)
                {
                    cts.Cancel();
                    availablePort = port;
                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }).ToList();
    }
    catch { }

    if (availablePort == -1)
        throw new ApplicationException("Not found available server port");

    return availablePort;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> WithCancellation<T>(this IEnumerable<T> en, CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (var item in en)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если нашли решение, можно его ответом оформить

Answer (score 0):

```
private static async Task<int> GetCurrentPort(IPAddress ip, IEnumerable<int> ports)
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    using var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(500);

    var availablePort = -1;

    try
    {
        _ = ports.OrderDescending().WithCancellation(cts.Token).Select(async port =>
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();

            try
            {
                var response = await $"http://{ip}:{port}".AppendPathSegment("ping").GetAsync(cts.Token);
                if (response.StatusCode is 200)
                {
                    cts.Cancel();
                    availablePort = port;
                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }).ToList();
    }
    catch { }

    if (availablePort == -1)
        throw new ApplicationException("Not found available server port");

    return availablePort;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> WithCancellation<T>(this IEnumerable<T> en, CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (var item in en)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        yield return item;
    }
}
```